# How to get the reference of a fragment created by FragmentTransaction.replace method

Tags: android, fragment, fragmenttransaction

I added a fragment inside an activity by using the following code：

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.parent_fragment_container, new FolderStructureFragment());
ft.commit();
```

My question is how can I get the reference of the added fragment. I have searched a lot of key words related to fragment and FragmentTransaction but didn't find anything close to my requirement which I think is a very basic function and should be offered to us. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the current fragment object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750069/get-the-current-fragment-object)

Answer (score 3):

There are the two major possiblities:

- You can remember the reference by yourself
- By an Tag
- By ID

For example (nearly the same for by ID):

```
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, tagOfFragment);
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tagOfFragment);
```

Comment: This does not work for me. It might be that I create and operate the fragment inside another fragment instead of an activity.

Comment: You should be able to find the fragment by the possibilites 2 and 3, no matter where you create it. Just call findFragmentByTag from the SupportFragmentManager.

Comment: i am always returned with null by calling getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tagOfFragment) or findFragmentByID(IDOfFragment);  I even tried getChildFragmentManager, but still no different.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581894/getfragmentmanager-findfragmentbytag-returns-null

Comment: Maybe I should try to test your approach in an activity to make sure this is not caused by doing it inside another fragment.

Comment: This sounds possible to work out. But I just found that I could retrieve the fragment by calling findFragmentByID now. I can do this in an onClick event. So I guess the reason I failed earlier was that it will take a little while to create and insert the fragment inside the parent ViewGroup so an immediate call to findFragmentByID following FragmentTransaction.commit is not able to find anything.

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTranscation(); could help to get it immediatelly

Comment: Yes, I think this is the right function I should take.

Answer (score 1):

try using the below code.

```
FolderStructureFragment folderStructureFragment = (FolderStructureFragment)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.parent_fragment_container);
```

Comment: try using `getChildFragmentManager()` to add or replace fragments inside another fragment instead of `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: That's sad. :(  You can keep the reference of the current fragment in another way. Create the fragment objects and store it in a `Fragment` class object. And in `replace` function use that `Fragment` class object instead of `new`-ing. So you will always have a reference to the currently loaded fragment. It's bit complicated solution, but it will get the work done.

Comment: This sounds possible to work out. But I just found that I could retrieve the fragment by calling findFragmentByID now. I can do this in an onClick event. So I guess the reason I failed earlier was that it will take a little while to create and insert the fragment inside the parent ViewGroup so an immediate call to findFragmentByID following FragmentTransaction.commit is not able to find anything.

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate your help:)

Answer (score 0):

```
    FolderStructureFragment folderStructureFragment = new FolderStructureFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.parent_fragment_container, folderStructureFragment);
    ft.commit();
```

Here , `folderStructureFragment` is reference for newly added fragment.

Comment: In my case, folderStructureFragment is not initialized with activity resources. Its just a simple new class rather than being a part of its parent activity.

Comment: Ok if it is a class it can be initialised this way and then `folderStructureFragment` can be used anywhere in your current activity as a reference to `FolderStructureFragment` class. Give a try.

Comment: This sounds possible to work out. But I just found that I could retrieve the fragment by calling findFragmentByID now. I can do this in an onClick event. So I guess the reason I failed earlier was that it will take a little while to create and insert the fragment inside the parent ViewGroup so an immediate call to findFragmentByID following FragmentTransaction.commit is not able to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to get a reference to a fragment any time you need, and that is with a TAG. Whenever you add a fragment you may give it a specific tag, and you may retrieve it anytime you want with that same TAG.

This is how you add it:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment,"myFragmentTag").commit();
```

Now let's say, somewhere in the code you need the reference to this fragment, you only need to call the following

```
MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("myFragmentTag");
if(myFragment != null && myFragment.isAdded()){ //you should always do this check when you retrieve fragment instances
    //do whatever you need with it
}
```

Comment: No luck for me. It might be that I create and operate the fragment inside another fragment but an activity.

Comment: That does not make a difference if you cast the fragment manager from the activity, i.e: `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: This sounds possible to work out. But I just found that I could retrieve the fragment by calling findFragmentByID now. I can do this in an onClick event. So I guess the reason I failed earlier was that it will take a little while to create and insert the fragment inside the parent ViewGroup so an immediate call to findFragmentByID following FragmentTransaction.commit is not able to find anything.

Comment: Check out my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43520688/findfragmentbyid-and-findfragmentbytag