# How to get current fragment in android using ById or ByTag

Tags: android, android-fragments, onbackpressed

In my main activity, i have a framelayout which is used to display fragments
now imagine, i have 3 fragment objects :

```
Fragment1 f1 = new Fragment1();
Fragment2 f2 = new Fragment2();
Fragment3 f3 = new Fragment3();
```

and i set this fragment using :

```
fragTrans.replace(android.R.id.content, f1);
fragTrans.addToBackStack(null);
fragTrans.commit();
```

now at different point of times, the app might have one of the three fragments in the framelayout (number of fragments might vary).

So, at some point if i want to identify which of the fragments if being currently displayed in the framelayout, how can i do that ?

My purpose :
the fragment2 has say 2 states, where boolean state can be either true or false, if the state is true, and the back button is pressed i want to do something and set state to false and the if the back is pressed i'll call super.onBackPressed() but if it is set to true and if currently fragment 3 is visible, first i want to go to fragment 2, then change the state to false and then super.onBackPressed()

so that will make it piece of cake if i can identify which fragment is currently visible

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750069/get-the-current-fragment-object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get currently displayed fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294603/get-currently-displayed-fragment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Your Solution is here**

**1.** First of you replace the fragment replace line with this line.

```
fragTrans.replace(android.R.id.content, f1,f1.getClass.getName());
```

Here **`f1.getClass,getName()`**  is key of current Fragment. it Gives you name of fragment which is replace or current replace fragment.

```
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        Fragment1 fragment1 = (Fragment1) manager.findFragmentByTag(Fragment1.class.getName());

        Fragment2 fragment2 = (Fragment2) manager.findFragmentByTag(Fragment2.class.getName());

        Fragment3 fragment3 = (Fragment3) manager.findFragmentByTag(Fragment3.class.getName());

        if (fragment1 != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Current fragment is Fragment1");
        }else if(fragment2 != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Current fragment is Fragment2");
        }else if(fragment3 != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Current fragment is Fragment3");
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Fragment 1-2-3 is null");
        }
```

If you do something on first time onBackPress Follow the code below,

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (isBackPress) { //Default is false
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            // On First time click do something 
               isBackPress=true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: But at any point of the app, none of the fragments will be null right ?

Comment: You have got a fragment that is currently open which is replaced with the use of the key.

Comment: Butt at anypoint none of the fragments will be null as i have declared the fragment variables as global in the class
SubjectFragment fs;
    CodeFragment cf;

so now how do i do this because at any point if i try both will be non-null

Comment: You are not understood my code. you have to learn android documentation.

Comment: Just tell me one thing,
Won't it be easier to find which Fragment is currently displayed in the FrameLayout by using manager.findFragmentById(R.id.FrameLayout) ? instead of checking the tags of each ? (Tell me a good reason why should i use findFragmentByTag instead of ByID ?)

Comment: Please Read this article : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43520981/7832102

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Fragment fragment = (Fragment)supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container)
```