# how can I pass data from recyclerview click to a fragment which is inside the same activity in which my recyclerview is placed?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-recyclerview

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final myViewHolder holder, final int position) {

            holder.tvItem.setText(itemList.get(position).getmTitle());
            Picasso.get().load(itemList.get(position).geturl()).into(holder.imgFlag);
                holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        final ModelClass model= itemList.get(position);

                    }
                });
```

Comment: I want to show data from my model class to fragment which is in same activity

Comment: Create an interface and method inside it which will return itemList or the data which you want to transfer. And implement that interface in your fragment.

Comment: would you give some hint in the form of code?

Comment: I have posted an example follow this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example you can follow this and fit as per your requirement-

Create an interface in your adapter

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
  void onItemClicked(int position, Object object);
}
```

in your adapter call

```
Adapter adapter = new Adapter(context, list, new Adapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(int position, Object object) {
                  // Handle Object of list item here
            }
        });
```

on your adapter

```
 private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener; // Global scope
```

in constructor call:

```
this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
```

on your item clicked event :

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      onItemClickListener.onItemClicked(position, _list.get(position));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one for single view and multiple view click

adapter viewholder class
      public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements
      View.OnClickListener {

```
        CircleImageView imgPlayer;
        TextView playerRole;


        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imgPlayer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.trnmt_player);
            playerRole = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pRole_id);

            playerRole .setOnClickListener(this);
            imgPlayer.setOnClickListener(this);


        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (v == imgPlayer) {

          onItemClickListener.onItemClicked(position,list.get(position));

                } else if(v==playerRole){

                  }

        }
      }
   }
```

interface

```
   public interface OnItemClickListener {
   void onItemClicked(int position, Object object); 
          }
```

inside adapter

```
      private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be helpful if you provide some snapshot of your code.
Although you can get callback of click action on recycler view on your activity. So for this you need to create your own Listener and set to your Custom adapter.

Creation of a Action Listener

```
 public interface ActionListener<T> {
     void onClickAction(int positionOfItem, T object);//here T will be the type of object bound to your view.
 }
```

Now create a method in your custom adapter to set this listener

```
private ActionListener mListener;

public void setActionListener(ActionListener listener){
     mListener = listener;
}
```

Now use this listener to navigate the call back from your adapter.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final myViewHolder holder, final int position) {

            holder.tvItem.setText(itemList.get(position).getmTitle());


Picasso.get().load(itemList.get(position).geturl()).into(holder.imgFlag);
            holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final ModelClass model= itemList.get(position);
                    listener.onClickAction(position, model);//this will pass the call to the listener.
                }
            });

}
```

Now set the listener to adapter in your activity class, where you just created the adapter instance. Here you need to invoke a method in your fragment. For getting the fragment you can use [findFramgentById() or findFragmentByTag()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43520688/findfragmentbyid-and-findfragmentbytag/43520981) methods.

```
adapter.setActionListener(new ActionListener<ModelClass>(){
    void onClickAction(int positionOfItem, ModelClass object){
         MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag();
         fragment.updateActionData(object);
    }
});
```

Please create a method in your fragment as given below :

```
public void updateActionData(ModelClass object){
     //to do your work with object
}
```

Hope this will work.